# discontinious hourly data in datatable, possible to insert missing hours datetime value and null for datavalue?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I am using the following stored procedure to retrieve data from an SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], DataValue, VariableID
  FROM DataValues
  WHERE SiteID = @siteID and VariableID = 1
 ) TableDate
PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([1])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

I then fill a DataSet DataTable with those values:

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
DataTable precip = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];
if (precip.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
  msPrec = precip.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("DateTime");
  sPrec = string.Join<object>(", ",
   from r in precip.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() select r[1]);
 }
else
 {
  msPrec = DateTime.MinValue;
  sPrec = "";
 }
```

In the above example msPrec is only a single value for the beginning of the dataset.

**The problem is that I didn't consider that the hourly data may not be continuous.**
  Meaning that there may be missing data which isn't stored as NULL in the database.  So it is entirely possible that one DB record is from 2013-04-26 04:00:00 and the next record in the DB is from 2013-04-26 08:00:00 with 05:00, 06:00, and 07:00 missing.

It is also possible that multiple days of data may be missing, not just some hours within the same day.

I am plotting this data with HighStock by HighCharts, much like shown in this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping except that they in the example pre-processed the data to include NULL values for missing data, as you can see by the data gaps in the plot.

The pseudo code to solve this problem is clear to me:
- loop through the output from the stored procedure
- compare current record DateTime to next records DateTime
- if nextRecordDateTime = currentRecordDateTime + 1 hour, proceed to next record
- if nextRecordDateTime != currentRecordDateTime + 1 hour, then
  calculate the difference between currentRecordDateTime and nextRecordDateTime in hours
  insert DateTime and DataValue (NULL) for each missing hour into DataTable
- continue loop at last inserted record

I looked at the [DataTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) on MSDN but didn't see anything that seemed relevant.  The [DataRow Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) would let me loop through the rows, but I am not clear on how I could obtain the value of the next row while in the current row.

So I have two questions;

How can I consider the DateTime value of the next record (row) while on the current record (row) of a DataSet DataTable?

How can I insert rows into a DataSet DataTable at the correct location, rather than add it to the end of the DataTable?  Or is the solution here to add it to the end and sort the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a piece of code that takes DataTable precip and inserts new rows with missing hour values. When the first column of the table has values 05:00, 07:00, 10:00; after the following operation, the output will be 05:00, 06:00, 07:00, 08:00, 09:00, 10:00.

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
        DataRow row;
        DateTime curRowDt, nextRowDt;
        object curObj, nextObj; // Used only for conversions

        for (int i = 0; i < precip.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
        {
            // Resetting id numbers
            precip.Rows[i][2] = i;

            // Throws exception when changed to
            // curRowDt = (DateTime)precip.Rows[i][0];
            curObj = precip.Rows[i][0];
            nextObj = precip.Rows[i + 1][0];
            curRowDt = Convert.ToDateTime(curObj);
            nextRowDt = Convert.ToDateTime(nextObj);

            if (curRowDt.AddHours(1.0) != nextRowDt)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < nextRowDt.Subtract(curRowDt).Hours; ++j)
                {
                    ++i;
                    row = precip.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = new object[] { curRowDt.AddHours(j), null, i };
                    precip.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
                }
            }
        }
        // Resetting last row's id number
        precip.Rows[precip.Rows.Count - 1][2] = precip.Rows.Count - 1;
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to code this up, especially as new user to stackoverflow, much appreciated indeed! :)    There are still a couple issues but I accepted the answer anyway because it gets me on the right track.    precip.Rows[i][2] = i; needs to be precip.Rows[i][1] = i; This is an off-by-one error, the item array only has two columns 0 and 1.  There is an "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table." error in the row.ItemArray line, not sure what the purpose of the i in the new object is, I think the i only belongs in precip.Rows.InsertAt, no?

Comment: there has been an interesting development, there is a case where data was missing for 566 hours from 9/7/2011 17:00 to 10/1/2011 7:00.  The code only inserted null values from 9/7/2011 18:00 to 9/8/2011 6:00 (13 values, not 566).  Quite curious.  Debugging now.

Comment: Update, the issue is that Subtract.Hours cannot deal with anything over 24 hours, so it cannot properly address the missing date if multiple days are missing.  Will post updated code in my "answer" below shortly.

Comment: No problem:) Thank you for explaining the question clearly. Id numbers would cause some problem if they were included in the table and must have been unique. By the way, you're right. Hours property can't hold hours more than 24. I hadn't realized that. TimeSpan solves it of course, but also nextRowDt.Subtract(curRowDt).TotalHours works.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this for completeness sake, this is the adjusted code that Mert Erol came up with in the accepted answer.  I believe that there was a miscommunication about whether ID numbers are required or not.  They are not.

The DataTable DataRows contain a ItemArray where the first column is the DateTime and the second column is the DataValue.

Here's Merl's code wrapped into a function that I am now using.  Thanks again Mert, I'd give you a few more upvotes if I could!

**EDIT: UPDATED** for correct handling of cases where data is missing for multiple days.  Using `TimeSpan` seemed most appropriate to get an accurate count of hours between data points.

```
public DataTable fillMissingHours(DataTable currentDataTable)
{
    // iterates through the current DataTable to find missing data and fill it in with
    // the correct DateTime and NULL DataValue
    DataRow row;
    DateTime curRowDt, nextRowDt;
    object curObj, nextObj; // Used only for conversions

    for (int i = 0; i < currentDataTable.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
    {
        curObj = currentDataTable.Rows[i][0];
        nextObj = currentDataTable.Rows[i + 1][0];
        curRowDt = Convert.ToDateTime(curObj);
        nextRowDt = Convert.ToDateTime(nextObj);

        if (curRowDt.AddHours(1.0) != nextRowDt)
        {
            TimeSpan deltaTime = nextRowDt - curRowDt;
            for (int j = 1; j < deltaTime.TotalHours; ++j)
            {
                ++i;
                row = currentDataTable.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = new object[] { curRowDt.AddHours(j), null };
                currentDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
            }
        }
    }

    return currentDataTable;
}
```